# How to convert String into ArrayList properly?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, list

I want to convert this `String` into an `ArrayList`

**String**

```
["one","two","three"]
```

I used this method

```
List<String> logopath = Arrays.asList(pos.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

I get this output from `logopath`

```
0 = "["one""
1 = ""two""
2 = ""three"]"
```

But I want the output of `logopath` to be like this:

```
0 = "one"
1 = "two"
2 = "three"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your string is actually valid JSON, so I would suggest using a JSON parser here:

```java
String input = "[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonArray items = gson.fromJson(input, JsonArray.class);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (JsonElement item : items) {
    String num = item.getAsString();
    list.add(num);
}

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Thank you so much , but items is `JsonArray` but I need List or Arraylist

Comment: Might this shorter version work in Java 16? `List<String> list = new Gson().fromJson( input, JsonArray.class ).stream().map( JsonElement :: getAsString ).toList()`

Comment: @Basil More typically I would have given your stream version (or something close to it), but I answered on a cell phone and so would not have been able to test it.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you, that should basically work too , but I use java 1.7 so I think I cannot use stream.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved as below,

```
String input[] = {"one","two","three"};
    List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String s:input){

        arrList.add(s);
    }
    System.out.print(arrList);
```

Comment: Thanks, but my String is just `string` not `string[]` , so I cannot apply it.